# Adding domain to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am writing a little app for Google App Engine.  I would like to point a domain I already own to my Google App Engine application.  This domain has been in my possession for years and is currently unused and parked at another host.

When I go to add my domain from my admin console, it sends me to the Google Apps signup page.  It looks like Google Apps is for gmail accounts, google drive space, etc, and I already have all these items.  I am not sure why it's trying to force me to signup for this account when I am trying to point a domain to my Google App Engine application.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I actually need a Google Apps account to point a domain to my GAE application?

I feel like I'm doing something wrong or missing something very obvious, but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sign up for Google Apps, but you do not have to use Gmail, etc., with this domain name if you don't want to. Google is trying to move all of its services to a single platform, which makes integration easier (e.g. authentication, user management, etc.)

Comment: Thanks.  It seemed so weird to require an Apps account for a I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Its in the docs. Yes in there it says the domain needs to be a google apps domain.